# How to deal with security in a javascript form with conditional fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

i'm doing my first custom form from scratch in javascript and php (is a wordpress site). And i'm dealing with some security issues.

i'm doing an conditional form, and for the sake of simplicity i'm using css to hide and show the fields (but i don't know if this is the best way to handle this).

my problem is that if some user opens the developers tools and changes the values of display it will sent all the field, even the one that supossed to be hidden.

is there any way to handle this problem?

i'm not using a plugin because the form has to many options and was difficult to maintain

Thank you

Comment: Validate the entries on the server. If there are fields you want to hide from the user, then don't load them on the first hand.

Comment: Yes that was my first approach, i was using a ajax call but was too slow, so i changed to show everything and hide.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is to never trust anything that the client does. In other words, you should never enforce security on the client. You can do client-side validation to help with the user experience, like having some alert if the user enters an invalid value for a field. However, as you correctly observe, there's nothing stopping clients from going into developer tools and modifying values to their liking.

I would suggest two changes: 1) only have the client request the necessary fields from the server if possible. This way, you don't even have to have this conditional logic in the frontend.  2) thoroughly validate the request on the server. Assume that the client can send you any request, and only accept valid form submissions on the server-side. You can only do so much to enforce anything client-side.

Comment: The first time that I do the form, was whith ajax but was too slow, So I changed to show and hide on the client side. But i will do comlpete validation on the server to avoid any problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to check all data validation in back end for security reasons. In front end side all data could be changed.
For example if you validate data by javascript, User can disable javascript and bypass your validations. It's highly NOT recommended to validate data only in client side. You should validate it in both Front end and Back end.